# Stripe subscriptions: How to get a customer's expired and/or canceled subscriptions?

Tags: stripe-payments

It's easy to get a customer's *current* subscriptions

```
const stripe = require('stripe')(stripeKey);
// ... 
let stripeCustomer = await stripe.customers.retrieve(customerId);
// stripeCustomer.subscriptions.data now contains an array of current subscriptions
```

But *expired/canceled* subscriptions are not in this array, and the only way to get subscriptions seems to be with their ID ([doc](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/retrieve?lang=node)).

Surely there is a way to get a customer's expired subscriptions with just that customer's ID?

(I'm using Node.js, but that's not very important.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out, there is a way to get subscriptions using a customer's ID.

```
let stripeSub = await stripe.subscriptions.list({customer: customerId});
```

To get canceled subscriptions, simply add `status: "canceled"`

```
let stripeSub = await stripe.subscriptions.list({customer: customerId, status: "canceled"});
```

`list` is documented too: [stripe docs](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/list).